# Should my map be able to use both types of latitude and longitude?

Tags: decimal, latitude-longitude

I hope this is the right place to post this. I'm a web designer who is doing a site for a client, except for their store location page, which I have contracted out to a Google map developer. The map needs to be searchable by lat and long, in both decimal and degrees/minutes/seconds. The programmer has it set up only for decimal, and says it will be a good deal of effort to make the search use both types.

Being a web designer myself, I know sometimes changes can take a while. However, I want to be sure what the programmer is saying is correct. I know that when I search Google maps in general, it can accept both types of lat and long measurements. I thought therefore, that a map customized to search lat and long via Google maps would also do this. Is that a correct assumption? Or could it potentially involve a good deal of work to make this happen? Should the programmer have assumed it would be searchable in both types of lat long?

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It does involve some work, but it's [not that difficult to do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_Decimal_Degree_to_DMS):

```
function deg_to_dms (deg) {
   var d = Math.floor (deg);
   var minfloat = (deg-d)*60;
   var m = Math.floor(minfloat);
   var secfloat = (minfloat-m)*60;
   var s = Math.round(secfloat);
   // After rounding, the seconds might become 60. These two
   // if-tests are not necessary if no rounding is done.
   if (s==60) {
     m++;
     s=0;
   }
   if (m==60) {
     d++;
     m=0;
   }
   return ("" + d + ":" + m + ":" + s);
}
```